# Excel calculate highest amount of color value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So basically i have this excel sheet

[image]

And i would want it to spit out the value of the columns with the most green, so in this case column 9.00, 10.00, and 11.00

Any way to do it with a formula?

Its colored based on value:
Green: 10.00 - 18.00

Yellow: 6.00 - 9.00, 19.00 - 22.00

Red: < 6.00 , > 22:00

Comment: You can do it with a formula based on the criteria not the color. If I get time I will write it up, unless someone else gets to it first.

Comment: ok thanks a lot! :)

Comment: what version of Excel?  Do you have Office 365 with TEXTJOIN?

Comment: i do not have office 365. its excel 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use COUNTIFS.  COUNTIFS requires ranges so we must use OFFSET to return each column individually to the COUNTIFS.  Then compare that to the MAX.  If they are equal then we return the title row to TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($A$2:$A$14,0,TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:24)-1)),">=10",OFFSET($A$2:$A$14,0,TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:24)-1)),"<=18")=MAX(COUNTIFS(OFFSET($A$2:$A$14,0,TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:24)-1)),">=10",OFFSET($A$2:$A$14,0,TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:24)-1)),"<=18")),$A$1:$X$1,""))
```

**Depending on one's version this array formula may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.**

[image]